# Porque no se refleja en bbdd una relación hecha en typeorm (nest.js)?

Tags: relaciones, nestjs, typeorm, migracion

Tengo un back hecho con typeOrm (nest.js) y ya he hecho muchas relaciones entre todas las tablas y bien, pero resulta que ahora estoy intentando una, q ya he revisado miles de veces y parece estar igual que las otras, pero no se refleja en la bbdd al hacer la migración y no doy con el error.
Adjunto imágenes de las relaciones por si hay algo q se me está escapando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Actualizo, la relación funcionaba correctamente, pero al añadir la otra relación, (el @ManyToOne de la línea 18 de consultingTeamLeader) la quita y pone la nueva, en vez de dejar ambas